# INSERT INTO sql query with muti rows got from select

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like to insert multiple rows into table, but value of each row will be got from subquery.

Here is pseudo code what do I want:

```
INSERT INTO Entries VALUES
                (
                    @Date,
                    (SELECT Users.ID 
                    FROM Users),
                    @Enter,
                    @Leave
                )
```

Where Users has multiple rows of course.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the `insert . . . select` form of insert:

```
INSERT INTO Entries
    SELECT @Date, Users.ID , @Enter, @Leave
    FROM Users;
```

You should get in the habit of explicitly listing the columns as well; this is good practice when using SQL.  Something like:

```
INSERT INTO Entries(Date, UserId, Enter, Leave)
    SELECT @Date, Users.ID , @Enter, @Leave
    FROM Users;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this untested query:

```
INSERT INTO Entries (SELECT @Date,Users.ID , @Enter,  @Leave FROM Users)
```